# Python - slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels, arima

I have a problem with using scipy's fmin solver. I wanted it to optimize parametres for my ARIMA model. When running code straight on (without fmin) everything works fine but when putting into optimizer there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "D:/Work/repo_python/bandwidth_estimation/estima.py", line 169, in <module>
    optimum = fmin(criterion, x0)   
File "C:\Users\Pigeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 442, in fmin
    res = _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)   
File "C:\Users\Pigeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 585, in _minimize_neldermead
    fsim[k] = func(sim[k])   
File "C:\Users\Pigeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 326, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))   
File "D:/Work/repo_python/bandwidth_estimation/estima.py", line 18, in criterion
    model_arima = ARIMA(train, order=parametres)   
File "C:\Users\Pigeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 988, in __new__
    mod.__init__(endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)   
File "C:\Users\Pigeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 1009, in __init__
    self._first_unintegrate = unintegrate_levels(self.endog[:d], d) 
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Here's the code:

```
def criterion(parametres):
    parametres = tuple(parametres)
    control_sum = 0
    train = [5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349]
    model_arima = ARIMA(train, order=parametres)
    model_arima_fit = model_arima.fit()

    predictions = model_arima_fit.forecast(steps=24)[0]
    for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
        control_sum += (predictions[i]-values[i])**2
    print(control_sum)
    return control_sum

x0 = [1,1,1]
optimum = fmin(criterion, x0)
```

As I said before - if I run code outside the function - everything works fine. The problem is when put it into function that lands in fmin solver.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `fmin` is passing in floats to the parameters and they need to be `int` you can fix it by casting `parametres` to int like this

`parametres = parametres.astype(int)`

and all together:

```
def criterion(parametres):
    parametres = parametres.astype(int)
    control_sum = 0
    train = [5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.545763155811349, 5.361409086288781, 5.899251779517743, 5.766256093003701, 5.795872889382786, 5.637485909370455, 5.7453759249241045, 5.066030606246879, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.0944229577563425, 5.545763155811349]
    print(parametres)
    model_arima = ARIMA(train, order=parametres)
    model_arima_fit = model_arima.fit()

    predictions = model_arima_fit.forecast(steps=24)[0]
    for i in range(0,len(predictions)):
        control_sum += (predictions[i]-values[i])**2
    print(control_sum)
    return control_sum

x0 = [1,1,1]
optimum = fmin(criterion, x0)
```

Also, you are using the variable `values` in your function while it is not defined in your function, that might cause problems as well.

NOTE: That in order to use this outside of `fmin` you will need to pass in a numpy array and not convert it to a tuple in your function.

Comment: @Pigeonnn, are you sure it actually worked?  You may have fixed the error, but it doesn't necessarily mean that `fmin` found a minimum.  `fmin` assumes the objective function is continuous.  If you cast the parameters to integers, you are violating the mathematical assumptions of `fmin`, so you might have convergence problems or incorrect results.

Comment: I thought so at first but after several tries I realised that it clearly can't find the minimum. I just thought that problem might be too simple or something.. I don't know what to do actually. Maybe other solver?